# I need help creating functions for my code

Tags: c

Maybe you could explain where exactly you want to split the code into seperate functions. You could also post your attempt at splitting it into functions so we can see what went wrong. – Andy Sukowski-Bang 17 hours ago
Ok thank i have added that then – Liam Fox 17 hours ago

You need to study how strings work in C before you attempt this program. If you are coming from a different programming language to C, then please not that there's no string class. char is just a single character. You have to form arrays with null termination and handle strings manually. – Lundin 16 hours ago

@Lundin Yeah he uses characters instead of strings in the entire code. And another problem is the fact that he tries to return multiple variable

Comment: Maybe you could explain where exactly you want to split the code into seperate functions. You could also post your attempt at splitting it into functions so we can see what went wrong.

Comment: Ok thank i have added that then

Comment: You need to study how strings work in C before you attempt this program. If you are coming from a different programming language to C, then please not that there's no string class. `char` is just a single character. You have to form arrays with null termination and handle strings manually.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah he uses characters instead of strings in the entire code. And another problem is the fact that he tries to return multiple variables with different datatypes from the method `GetDetails()`.

Comment: Why did you edit your question? Now it contains the comments below your question...

Comment: @LiamFox You urgently need to take the [tour] and read some of the support pages. This is not the way StackOverflow works. -- Very short: You post a question, edit it to react on comments, anyone possibly posts one or more answers, and you possibly mark the right answer. But never replace your question with comments or answers, please! It renders this post useless. You should delete it completely if you think it is of no help to others.

Answer (score 1):

## Return values

You can't easily return multiple variables with different datatypes from a function. There are multiple solutions to solving this problem. Only implement *one* of the two solutions.

### Data structure

Create a data structure like this:

```
struct customer {
    char name[20];
    int license;
    int days;
};
```

Then you could create an object of the struct type in the method `GetDetails`, initialize it's variables and return the object:

```
struct customer custm;
custm.name = "John Doe";
custm.license = 3142;
custm.days = 365;

return custm;
```

The method would have to be of type `struct customer`.

```
struct customer get_details(void)
```

But it's more advisable to only pass a pointer to the struct instead of passing it by value, so in the example code that I've provided below, I will pass a pointer.

### Pass pointers

You could declare the method `GetDetails` like this instead:

```
void get_details(char *name, int *license, int *days);
```

You would then have to call the method like this:

```
char name[20];
int license;
int days;
get_details(name, &license, &days);
```

And inside the method you would have to dereference the integers.

```
*license = 3142;
```

## Read user input

I would store the customer's name in a string and read it using the `%[^\n]` specifier.

```
/* choose appropriate length */
char name[20];
printf("Enter the customer's name: ");
/* prevent buffer overflow */
scanf("%19[^\n]", name);
```

Alternatively you could use `fputs` and `fgets`.

```
/* choose appropriate length */
char name[20];
fputs("Enter the customer's name: ", stdout);
/* prevent buffer overflow */
fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
/* replace '\n' with '\0' in name */
size_t len = strlen(name);
name[len - 1] = '\0';
```

Ideally you should also check the [return value of `scanf`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/return-values-of-printf-and-scanf-in-c):

```
int license;
fputs("Enter the customer's license number: ", stdout);
if (scanf("%d", &license) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid input\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

## Entire code

I have now rewritten your entire code and implemented a customer data structure. You had a lot of unnecessary code in `SortHire` as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct customer {
    char name[20];
    int license;
    /* can only be positive */
    unsigned int days;
};

/* get customer details from user input */
struct customer *get_details(void)
{
    struct customer *custm = malloc(sizeof *custm);
    if (!custm) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fputs("Enter the customer's name: ", stdout);
    fgets(custm->name, sizeof(custm->name), stdin);
    /* replace '\n' with '\0' in name */
    size_t len = strlen(custm->name);
    custm->name[len - 1] = '\0';

    fputs("Enter the customer's license number: ", stdout);
    if (scanf("%d", &custm->license) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Enter the length of hire for %s: ", custm->name);
    if (scanf("%u", &custm->days) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return custm;
}

/* calculate total rental cost */
void sort_hire(struct customer *custm)
{
    const float shortcost = 34.50;
    const float mediumcost = 30.50;
    const float longcost = 22.50;

    const float shorthire = 1;
    const float mediumhire = 4;
    const float longhire = 8;

    float cost;
    if (custm->days < mediumhire)
        cost = custm->days * shortcost;
    else if (custm->days < longhire)
        cost = 3* shortcost + (custm->days - 3) * mediumhire;
    else if(custm->days >= longhire)
        cost = 3 * shortcost + 4 * mediumcost +
                (custm->days - 7) *  longcost;

    /*
     * There is no need to print exactly the same
     * in every code block. Just do it after the
     * if-else-statements.
     */
    printf("\n  Summary of Hire\n"
           "  ---------------\n"
           "  Customer: %s\n"
           "  License No: %d\n"
           "  Number of days: %u\n"
           "  ---------------\n"
           "  Total rental cost: %f\n\n",
           custm->name, custm->license, custm->days, cost);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct customer *custm = get_details();
    sort_hire(custm);

    /* free manually allocated memory */
    free(custm);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how ever its just focusing on the functions.

Comment: @LiamFox I have now rewritten your entire code, implemented my suggestions and fixed all your mistakes.

Comment: @LiamFox If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.